# Allow access to specific user only

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I have a database with an owner for it. My problem is that, though I have assigned a password for the owner, any other database user can access this database locally, even without a password.

How can I configure the database so that only a specific user has access to it (only with right password)?

Comment: I think you need to tighten the config in your `pg_hba.conf`.

Comment: `revoke connect on database your_db_name from public; grant connect on database your_db_name to your_user;`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to edit your [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file.  If you really want to reduce possible access to a single user (see the note below), you will need the following lines, and only these:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE  USER       ADDRESS   METHOD
host    all       dbowner    all       md5
local   all       dbowner              md5
```

This means that only `dbowner` will have access to any DB, logging in via the Unix socket or a TCP connection (from all addresses, including `localhost`).  You can replace 'all' with your DB name if you want to limit access to a single DB.

After having edited the file, you will have to reload the config - depending on your system, do a `pg_ctl reload` or `kill -HUP <postmaster_pid>`, or do this form inside the DB, by calling

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Please note that in the future you might want to do certain things that need rights `dbowner` may not have (be it `SUPERUSER`, `CREATEUSER` or something else).  Depending on the policy you follow, you'll have to edit the file again to allow further access to a user (eg. `postgres`) that has the necessary privileges, or you have to assign these to `dbowner` before closing the door on other users.

Comment: I am going to try this. Thank you for the help.